# It's possible to navigate to a https website on android 4.0.3 emulator using a client certificate?

Tags: android, eclipse, https, android-emulator

I am trying to create an Android application that send information from the device invoking a https webservice.

I am getting this error:
    SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

So I want to test if I really have access to the webservice URL using the Android's default Browser.
So the website show me the screen from the uplaoded image, asking me for Install the certificate, then asking me for the password, all OK but nothing happens.
The Broswser just keep trying to connect with no luck.
Then I refresh to enter to the URL again, and this time I hit Allow but nothing happens again.

(I put the client certificate .p12 on the SD card via File Explorer on DDMS perspective on Eclipse)

It's possible to browse to an URL like this in an Android emulator?
(Android 4.0.3 API level 15)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I got a "Security warning" then I hit Continue and I could see the WSDL file of my webservice.

[image: Results]